# Confusion in basic trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry, angle

[image]

We know when $\theta$ is acute, cos $\theta$ is positive. However in the above diagram, the adjacent side is negative and hence cos $\theta$ should be negative.
This is obviously incorrect. Where am I wrong?

Comment: You are measuring the wrong angle.  The measure you want (in quadrant II) corresponds to $\pi - \theta$, which has a negative cosine.

Comment: We, by convention measuring angles from the positive part of $x$-axis in a counterclockwise manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For convention angles are misured from **positive x** axis **counterclockwise** direction.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to your thinking, but using your own terms, the adjacent side is positive. Because you are counting the angles *from the positive side*.

In the figure, the right side of the $x$ axis plays no role (other than misleading you).

Answer (score 0):

In the end, this boils down to the fact that $\cos(\theta)$ does not depend on how you draw $\theta$.

That said, depending on the problem you'd like to solve, the correct angle to consider might be $\pi - \theta$, rather than $\theta$.